# How to see commits by user accross multiple repositories in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-log

I want to see the commits by a user across all repositories in my organization in Azure DevOps. I cannot see such options available.

I can see the below option in Azure DevOps, but it shows commits in a single repository.

[image]

I know we can use the below git command to see the commits in a single repository.

```
git log --author<AuthorName> --all ( or --branches)
```

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT sorry, I couldn't work on this item, I will verify today and update you

Comment: Hi, You could try it and share the results here. If you have any follow-up questions, you can also share them here and I will still be here to help you. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check this REST API sample [By author](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#by-author), it contain the filed author, we could enter Alias or display name of the author to list all commit info.

In addition, we could add the filed `searchCriteria.itemVersion.version` to filter branch.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name}/commits?searchCriteria.author={searchCriteria.author}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={branch name}&api-version=6.0
```

> I want to see the commits by a user across all repositories in my organization in Azure DevOps

a. List all projects via org name and get the project name.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0
```

b. List all repos via org name and project name and get the repo name.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0
```

c. List all branches via org name, project name and repo name, then get branch name

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name}/refs?filter=heads&api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

d. List commit info via Alias or display name of the author

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo name}/commits?searchCriteria.author={searchCriteria.author}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version={branch name}&api-version=6.0
```

Power shell script:

```
cls

#List all projects via org name
$ListAllProjectsURL="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
$PAT="{pat}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

#get the project name
$ListAllProjects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ListAllProjectsURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

ForEach ($ProjectName in $ListAllProjects.value.name){
    #Write-Host $ProjectName
    #List all repos via org name and project name and get the repo name.
    $ListAllRepoURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/$($ProjectName)/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.0"
    $ListAllRepo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ListAllRepoURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

    ForEach ($RepoName in $ListAllRepo.value.name){
        #Write-Host $RepoName
        $ListAllBranchURL ="https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/$($ProjectName)/_apis/git/repositories/$($RepoName)/refs?filter=heads&api-version=6.1-preview.1"                          
        $ListBranchName = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ListAllBranchURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get
        #get branch name
        foreach($Branch in $ListBranchName.value){
            $BranchName = $Branch.name.split("/",3)[-1]
            #write-host $BranchName

            #List the commits by a user across all repositories in one organization in Azure DevOps
            $ListCommitInfoViaUserURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{org name}/$($ProjectName)/_apis/git/repositories/$($RepoName)/commits?searchCriteria.author={User display name}&searchCriteria.itemVersion.version=$($BranchName)&api-version=6.0"
            $ListCommitInfo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $ListCommitInfoViaUserURL -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

            if($ListCommitInfo.count -eq 0){

            }else{
                Write-Host "Project name is:"$ProjectName "    repo name is:" $RepoName    "branch name is:" $BranchName    "and commit ID is:" $ListCommitInfo.value.commitId 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I tried the APIs it looks good. but I have never worked on Powershell, so I request you to either convert it to C# code, or let me know how I can do it?

Comment: I found [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#assemble-the-request), it get a list of team projects in a Azure DevOps Services organization, you could refer to it to convert the power shell script to C# code.

Comment: What is PAT? the authentication mechanism? if so, how do I generate it? is it a token that I need to generate on Azure DevOps under my account?

Comment: The rest api is the same in every language, just use the same endpoints and api calls and it is language agnostic